# How to correctly manage iframe to give the user similar UI look-and-feel between two applications

Tags: web, iframe, cloud

I am trying to figure out a correct yet simple way to solve the following problem.
We have a web application that is exposed on the web where authorized people can operate.
These people needs to work on this web application and on a cloud hosted tool to perform similar actions.
As matter of fact, we want the people to have a similar interface (with almost all the elements from the first application) inside the cloud hosted tool.
We cannot deploy a new instance of the first application on the cloud hosted tool but we can insert a Web view with an iframe recalling the first application.

The scenario, ideally, will then be:

```
cloud.domain.com > [iframe]:a.my-domain.com
```

What is not clear to me are the following:

1. Being a.my-domain.com under SSO and being the people connected to a corporate network (where a.my-domain.com resides), will cookies and SSO still work inside the iframe (i.e. not requiring the user to authenticate two times on the application)?
2. Is there a clean way to manipulate the application inside the iframe without having to modify the source code (i.e. just changin the visibility of some elements)?

For point 2. I found out that this won't be possible if the caller application is on a different domain of the called one, but it is not clear if with `jQuery` or `postMessage` this can be done (with `postMessage` I understood we need to modify the called application).

Does anybody know if the explained solution will work for the initial requirement?